# Comparing the dates with cases and Datedifference method

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an sheet named as Result.

In this sheet, I have column H with s.Date and Start date in column I.

The column H is completely filled and column I has empty rows sometime.

I am having cases as stated below,

Case1. If the start date is > 4 weeks of S.Date then it is ontime and highlighted as green

case2: if the start date is > 8 weeks of S.Date then it is delay.

Case3: if the start date is between 4 to 8 weeks, then it is Remaining, it is yellow.

case 4: where the start date is earlier than the S.date , in this case also, it should be green.

All the above three cases are achieved,  but I am struck how to achieve 4th case. 
Can anyone suggest, how i could do it. Have attached an Image also, for reference. I have posted this already, but there is no postive repsonse or Chat to clarify my doubt. Sorry for the repost, but i would like to clarify this issue. Expecting the help from Forum.

```
Option Explicit

Sub status()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim zWeeks As Double, zcolour As Long
    Dim Ztext As String
    Set ws = Sheets("Result")
    With ws
        lrow = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 5 To lrow
            zWeeks = DateDiff("ww", .Range("I" & i).Value, .Range("H" & i).Value)
            If .Range("E" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("F" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("I" & i).Value = "" Then
                Ztext = "remaining"
                zcolour = vbYellow
                Cells(i, 11) = "Yellow"
            ElseIf .Range("F" & i).Value = "" And .Range("I" & i).Value = "" Then
                GoTo nextrow
            ElseIf zWeeks < 4 Then
                Ztext = "  on time"
                zcolour = vbGreen
                Cells(i, 11) = "Green"
            ElseIf zWeeks > 8 Then
                Ztext = " delayed"
                zcolour = vbRed
                Cells(i, 11) = "Red"
            ElseIf zWeeks > 4 < 8 Then
                Ztext = "Remaining"
                zcolour = vbYellow
                Cells(i, 11) = "Yellow"
            End If
            With .Range("J" & i)
                .Value = Ztext
                .Interior.Color = zcolour
            End With
nextrow:
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: The Image below Shows the result that is needed. Could someone help to achieve the last case, as mentioned.]

Answer (score 0):

As far i understood, Case 4 should return a negative value from the above so you can used a condition as below
Add one more formula

```
zdays = DateDiff("d", .Range("I" & i).Value, .Range("H" & i).Value) '**Checknotes below

elseif zweeks < 0 or zdays < 0 or zdays = 0 then
   Cells(i, 11) = "Green"
End if
```

**Notes:
1. zdays will handle the dates within the same week
2. This will return negative value

Comment: so you mean to tell, i could use days, instead of weeks in my case ?

Comment: It is not returning any negative number

Comment: I tried it eliminating the weeks and following the days, it gets printed green. all over

Comment: use the zdays formulae just below the zweeks . Also zdays will only work with zweeks and zdays used with or condition as mention in my answe. To be safer side use zdays only on the 4th case

Comment: as mentioned, i tried and i am still not able to achieve the target. is there anyother way I could do it ? could yu suggest me